# Cannot install Business Contact Manager for Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, business-contact-manager

I am attempting to install BCM for Outlook 2010 on several PCs. The installation process seems to be hit or miss. All PCs are Windows 7 x64 with latest updates and Office 2010 Pro with latest updates.

Some PCs get an error when running the full BCM installer: "Business Contact Manager requires that Outlook be installed on the computer."
All PCs have outlook profiles setup and used everyday without issue. Other programs like Shoretel installed add-ins without issue. It only seems to be this program that cannot see Outlook is installed, and the behavior is not consistent.

This is the link for the full BCM installers: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36513

I have tried uninstall/reinstall with Microsoft's Fixit tool here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971179

I also tried disabling Kaspersky AV, installing in Safe mode, from a new user profile (local and from domain), running sfc /snannow from cmd and chkdsk, no luck.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks

Below are the BCM installer logs.

Log from problem PC

```
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Business Solutions eCRM\4.0, InstallPath, Bit32)
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Business Solutions eCRM\4.0, InstallPath, Bit64)
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$MSSMLBIZ, DisplayName, Bit32)
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] Boolean ProductIsInstalled(System.String): Product code {41785C66-90F2-40CE-8CB5-1C94BFC97280} not found
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] Boolean PrerequisitesExist(System.String ByRef): [BCMHook] Outlook not installed.
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.Collections.ArrayList GetApplicationList(): Product BCM. Prerequisites check failed:
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] System.Collections.ArrayList GetApplicationList(): Business Contact Manager requires that Outlook be installed on the computer.
[3/16/2016 10:10 PM] Void Main(System.String[]): Caught BcmException. Wizard exiting.
```

Log from PC where BCM install completed successfully

```
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Business Solutions eCRM\4.0, InstallPath, Bit32)
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Business Solutions eCRM\4.0, InstallPath, Bit64)
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$MSSMLBIZ, DisplayName, Bit32)
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] Boolean ProductIsInstalled(System.String): Product code {41785C66-90F2-40CE-8CB5-1C94BFC97280} not found
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] Boolean ProductIsInstalled(System.String): Product code {E4B48349-A165-4097-8D78-AC950BD8638E} not found
[3/15/2016 3:54 PM] Boolean ProductIsInstalled(System.String): Product code {050BF7DA-82C4-416A-8294-7AFEB8ED94E1} not found
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Void Install(): Processing application Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (MSSMLBIZ); Installed False; UseWizardForUninstall True
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Boolean ShouldApplicationBeInstalled(): App Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (MSSMLBIZ) - bShouldApplicationBeInstalled is True
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Void Install(): Calling SQL's PreInstall() hook.
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): IsApplicationInstalled(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100, VerSpecificRootDir, Bit32)
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] System.String IsApplicationInstalled(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.Bitness): Returns ""
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\temp\BcmSetup.en-US\SSE\sqlexpr.exe /q /x:C:\BcmSqlSetup
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 3:57 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): C:\BcmSqlSetup\setup.exe /q /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=RunRules /RULES=RebootRequiredCheck
[3/15/2016 3:58 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 3:58 PM] Boolean IsMsiExecBusy(): _MSIExecute mutex cannot be opened. Available to use. Continuing.
[3/15/2016 3:58 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): C:\BcmSqlSetup\setup.exe /q /HIDECONSOLE /X86 /ACTION=Install /Features=SQLEngine,FullText /INSTANCENAME=MSSMLBIZ /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): App SQL install returned 0
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): Calling SQL's PostInstall() hook.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Boolean PostInstall(): [SqlHook] Stopping Sql service MSSQL$MSSMLBIZ
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL data for value MSSMLBIZ is MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetRegistryData(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind): [SqlHook] Set key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPALL value TcpPort to 5356.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetRegistryData(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind): [SqlHook] Set key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPALL value TcpDynamicPorts to .
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg0 is -dC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg1 is -eC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg2 is -lC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg3 not found.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetSQLTraceFlag(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Setting SQL trace flag.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetRegistryData(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind): [SqlHook] Set key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg3 to -T840.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg0 is -dC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg1 is -eC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg2 is -lC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg3 is -T840.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg4 not found.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetSQLTraceFlag(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Setting SQL trace flag.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetRegistryData(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind): [SqlHook] Set key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg4 to -T2324.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg0 is -dC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg1 is -eC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg2 is -lC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg3 is -T840.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters data for value SQLArg4 is -T2324.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.Object GetRegistryData(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Under key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg5 not found.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetSQLTraceFlag(System.String, System.String): [SqlHook] Setting SQL trace flag.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetRegistryData(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind): [SqlHook] Set key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSMLBIZ\MSSQLServer\Parameters value SQLArg5 to -T1802.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetForceEncryption(System.String, Boolean): [SqlHook] Setting Sql Server ForceEncryption flag in instance MSSMLBIZ to True.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Boolean PostInstall(): [SqlHook] Starting SQL service.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] System.String ConnectionString(System.String): [SqlHook] Sql connection string is: Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master;server=EECWS06\MSSMLBIZ;Connect Timeout=30;Pooling='no'
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetSQLServerConfiguration(System.String): [SqlHook] Configuring advanced options of BCM sql instance.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void ExecuteSQLCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String): [SqlHook] Running sql command: sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void ExecuteSQLCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String): [SqlHook] Running sql command: RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void SetSQLServerConfiguration(System.String): [SqlHook] Configuring minimum memory of BCM sql instance.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void ExecuteSQLCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String): [SqlHook] Running sql command: sp_configure 'min server memory (MB)', 128
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void ExecuteSQLCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String): [SqlHook] Running sql command: RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): Processing application Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5; Installed False; UseWizardForUninstall False
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Boolean ShouldApplicationBeInstalled(): App Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 - bShouldApplicationBeInstalled is True
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Boolean IsMsiExecBusy(): _MSIExecute mutex cannot be opened. Available to use. Continuing.
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): msiexec.exe  /i "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\temp\BcmSetup.en-US\MSChart\datavisualization_setupcore.msi" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Small Business" ALLUSERS=1  /l*vx "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\BCMsetuptmp519C.log"
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): App MSChart install returned 0
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): Processing application Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook; Installed False; UseWizardForUninstall True
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Boolean ShouldApplicationBeInstalled(): App Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook - bShouldApplicationBeInstalled is True
[3/15/2016 4:03 PM] Void Install(): Calling BCM's PreInstall() hook.
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void DetachV1V2Databases(): [BCMHook] SqlException thrown: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean IsMsiExecBusy(): _MSIExecute mutex cannot be opened. Available to use. Continuing.
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): msiexec.exe  /i "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\temp\BcmSetup.en-US\MSSMLBIZ.msi" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Small Business" BOOTSTRAPPED=1 ALLUSERS=1  /l*vx "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\BCMsetuptmp547A.log"
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void Install(): App BCM install returned 0
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void Install(): Calling BCM's PostInstall() hook.
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean IsBCM32V4Installed(): [BCMHook] BCM v4 32 product code not installed.
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean StartSqlExprService(): [BCMHook] StartSqlExprService(): Calling WaitForDatabaseConnectivity()
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void WaitForDatabaseConnectivity(System.String, Int32): [BCMHook] checking connectivity - dsn=Persist Security Info=False;initial catalog=master;server=EECWS06\MSSMLBIZ;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=False;enlist=false
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] ConnectionStatus CheckConnectionStatus(System.String): [BCMHook] DSN=Persist Security Info=False;initial catalog=master;server=EECWS06\MSSMLBIZ;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=False;enlist=false
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void WaitForDatabaseConnectivity(System.String, Int32): [BCMHook] Status=Available
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void WaitForDatabaseConnectivity(System.String, Int32): [BCMHook] successfully connected
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void Install(): Processing application Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook English Language Pack; Installed False; UseWizardForUninstall True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean ShouldApplicationBeInstalled(): App Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook English Language Pack - bShouldApplicationBeInstalled is True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean IsMsiExecBusy(): _MSIExecute mutex cannot be opened. Available to use. Continuing.
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): msiexec.exe  /i "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\temp\BcmSetup.en-US\LangPack.en-US\MSSMLBIZLPK.msi" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Small Business" BOOTSTRAPPED=1 ALLUSERS=1 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  /l*vx "C:\Users\agonzalez.EECWORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\BCMLPen-USwizinstalltmp9A52.log"
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Int32 RunProcess(System.String, System.String): Returning 0
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void Install(): App LangPack install returned 0
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void InstallExtraLangPacks(): Found 0 additional language packs
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean AreAllAppsInstalled(): ApplicationName Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (MSSMLBIZ) Required: True, Installed: False, InstallSucceeded: True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean AreAllAppsInstalled(): ApplicationName Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Required: True, Installed: False, InstallSucceeded: True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean AreAllAppsInstalled(): ApplicationName Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook Required: False, Installed: False, InstallSucceeded: True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Boolean AreAllAppsInstalled(): ApplicationName Business Contact Manager for Microsoft Outlook English Language Pack Required: True, Installed: False, InstallSucceeded: True
[3/15/2016 4:04 PM] Void OnActivate(Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusiness.SetupWizard.WizardDirection): Success: All components are installed.
```

Comment: you should install BCM x64 if you have Office x64

Comment: @Scorpion99 I have x86 Office installed.
It's also weird that if I run the installer with outlook or any other office application running, it recognizes that it's running; just not installed. If I try running the x64 installer, it throws an error saying I need to run x86 installer for my version of office.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my constellation, the problem was generated by the leftover of a newer Office Trial Version in registry. After I removed the following registry key, the installation works:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0

Before that the Office Trial Version was removed via Control Panel.